# Distribution of $Z=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i \sqrt{X_i}$

Tags: probability-distributions, solution-verification, chi-squared

I found a question given by my teacher which went like this:

> Suppose $X_0,X_1,...,X_n$ are i.i.d. random variable following $\chi_1^2$ distribution. Then by proving necessary result, find the distribution of $Z=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i \sqrt{X_i}$ where $c=\left(c_1,c_2,...c_n\right)'$ is a vector of known constants.

So here's what I tried till now:

Let $X\sim\chi^2_n$. Then
$$f_X\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^{n/2-1}e^{-x/2}}{2^{n/2}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)},& x\geq0\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Then, to find the distribution of $Y'=\sqrt{X}$, I used the transformation technique and proceeded as follows:
$$f_{Y'}\left(y'\right)=f_X\left(y'^2\right)\left|\frac{dy'^2}{dy'}\right|=\frac{\left(y'^2\right)^{n/2-1}e^{-y'/2}}{2^{n/2}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}2y'=\frac{y'^{n-1}e^{-b^2/2}}{2^{n/2-1}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)} ,y'\geq0$$
As, $X_1,X_2,...,X_n\sim\chi^2_1$, I replaced the $n$ in the above pdf by $1$ and thus got the pdf of $\sqrt{X_1},\sqrt{X_2},...,\sqrt{X_n}$ as
$$f_{X_i}\left(x_i\right)=\frac{\sqrt{2}e^{-x_i^2/2}}{\sqrt{\pi}},x_i\geq0$$
This seems like the pdf of a Half Normal Distribution.

This is all I did and I could go no further. Can anyone suggest me some hints as to how to go ahead in this problem? Also, did I do any mistake till now, like approaching the problem in this manner cause I don't know how to proceed any further. Alternative solution suggestions are very much welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let's denote $Y_i = \sqrt{X_i}$. As $Y_i$ are i.i.d and follows the [half-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution), perhaps you could find the distribution of $Z$ by using the characteristic function

\begin{align}
E(e^{itZ}) &= E\left(e^{it\sum_{i=1}^n c_i\sqrt{X_i}}\right) 
= \prod_{i=1}^n E\left(e^{itc_i Y_i}\right) =\prod_{i=1}^n \phi_{Y_i}(c_it)
\end{align}

Using Mathematica, the characteristic function of half normal distribution is
$$\phi_{Y_i}(t) = e^{-\frac{\pi t^2}{4}}\left(1+\mathbf{i} \text{ Erfi}\left( \frac{\pi t}{2} \right)  \right)$$
where $\text{Erfi}(t)$ is the [imaginary error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html).

Comment: Well, I missed this part. It is going to be a somewhat clumsy expression I guess...